# FullCalendar end daily event

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, fullcalendar

How can I know the first and last day of a daily event?
For example, I have an event every day at 8am, from the 15-08-2018 until the 17-08-2018, when clicking on the event in the calendar, I want to know the date of the last day of the event, the 08-17-2018

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eventClick` event for the clicking of the event then you access the event data inside that function.

For more info read: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick

```js
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
      {
        "title": "Event 1",
        "start": "2018-08-10T08:00:00+08:00",
        "end": "2018-08-15T07:59:59+08:00",
      },
      {
        "title": "Event 2",
        "start": "2018-08-20T08:00:00+08:00",
        "end": "2018-08-25T07:59:59+08:00",
      }
  ],
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    alert(calEvent.start);
    alert(calEvent.end);
  }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```